# How can I send array of Candidates ID to different rows of candidates table?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, laravel-5.3

**Hello, this is a form of candidates which contains a checkbox at each rows. And from those checkboxes I can select four at most. How can I send those four at a time as array and insert them in different four rows of 'Candidates' table? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.**

```
<form id="cforms" method="post">
         {{ csrf_field() }}             
          @unless($cforms->count())
          <h1>There are no forms submitted yet!</h1>
          @else 
          <table>
            <thead>
              <th  font-weight="bold"> Select</th>
              <th  font-weight="bold"> Student-ID</th>
            </thead>

            @foreach($cforms as $candidates) 
            <tr>  
            <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="Candidates_ID" value= 
  "{{$candidates->s_id}}">
             </td>
             <td>{{$candidates->s_id}}</td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
          </table></br>
         @endunless
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should make each checkbox's name unique. If you change your input fields as shown selections will be grouped together in an array when you access them in PHP.

`<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="Candidates_ID[{{$candidates->s_id}}]" value="true">`

You can then get the selected Id's in PHP like below

`$ids = array_keys($_POST['Candidates_ID']);`

Comment: But @Thakkie, will I get the Id's in different rows in candidates table? Additionally I am working with Laravel if it helps though.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I was working under the assumption that you knew how to insert data into a database. I think the I can best refer you to the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#inserts) for that, as I have no idea what your setup and database structure is like.

Comment: Yeah, appreciate your help @Thakkie